# How can I call a function in a controller from outside the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.doSomething = function(){
    alert("Do something!");
  }

}
```

And I have multiple views which depend on this (ie multiple of the below):

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    ...
  </div>
```

The problem is, the data the controller depends on needs to be loaded in the background (the controller does not load that data), and a callback (dataIsReady()) will be called after the data is ready.

```
function dataIsReady(){
  // TODO: call the doSomething() function
}
```

Now, I want to basically call the doSomething() function, which is inside MyCtrl,  from the dataIsReady() function. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know angularJS, but the answer in other languages would be to move the function into an outer scope, then call it from both places.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need is a data service, which you can then inject into your controller. You can call a function on your data service which will handle the retrieval of the data and return a "promise" which can then be used to trigger your callback function when the data has loaded. 
Have a look at the following code which is a slightly modified version from egghead.io:

**Plunker Demo (w/ local storage):**   http://plnkr.co/edit/9w2jTg?p=preview

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('AvengersService', function ($http) {

    var AvengersService = {
        getAsyncCast: function () {           
            // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
            var promise = $http.get("avengers.json") // or some JSON service
                .then(function (response) {
                   // The 'then' function here is an opportunity to modify the response
                   // The return value gets picked up by the 'then' in the controller.
                   return response.data;
            });
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promise;
        }
    };

    return AvengersService;
});

myApp.controller('AvengersCtrl', function($scope, AvengersService) {
    // Call the async method and then do something when the data is retrieved
    AvengersService.getAsyncCast()
        .then(function (asyncData) {
            // Callback logic that depends on the data goes in here
            console.info("Cast pulled async.");
            $scope.avengers.cast = asyncData;
        });              

});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there a simpler way I can do this? My app is a pretty simple CRUD app and I don't want the Angular JS stuff to complicate it more than necessary...I also don't mind if a quick hack-around if it's shorter code wise (ie. somehow scope into the div and run that function). I'm trying to rapidly prototype an app while maintaining some standard of consistency. While I understand all of the code above, I just have a bunch of controllers which are waiting for some data to be loaded in the background.

Comment: @oxuser: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean when you say "scope into the div". If you set up a jsfiddle or plunker I'd be happy to take look for you. Another possible approach to this would be to add a data service to the `$rootScope` and use `$broadcast` to notify all listening controllers when data has been retrieved by using `$scope.$on`. See example here: [http://jsfiddle.net/gavinfoley/XCeK3/](http://jsfiddle.net/gavinfoley/XCeK3/)

Answer (score 2):

**Notice:** This approach in this answer is terribly wrong, one should not access to the scope of a controller outside of angular, or outside of controller at all. This would also be terribly slow if you try to call it several times. Other than that, it is fine. I am giving this answer because it is also the simplest way. I would never use that kind of code in production, though. The appropriate way is to write a service to communicate with the controller.

Given that you have defined `$scope.doSomething` in `MyCtrl`:

```
var scp = angular.element('[ng-controller="MyCtrl"]').scope();
scp.doSomething();
```

Will call `doSomething` method defined in the controller.